# Enable Compression of Asp.Net WebAPI payload request from IIS Manager

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, compression, http-compression, iis-manager

I want compress my request payload before going to the api request call. I want to compression the request payload from IIS. any settings will solve my problem

I want to se

Comment: As far as I know, this cannot be done in IIS, the compression function of IIS only supports static files and dynamic application responses, you can try it in the application.